# Create a special kind of graph

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, graph

I have created a vb.net form that adds value to an access database i.e .mdb file. Different values are added every second as I have set timers. I have a memory field to which values are updated every second. I have 2 such records to find memory of 2 different processes.

Now my question is how can I create a **graph**, that will show me the changes made to the memory fields. The graph should be dynamic. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate the Windows Forms' [Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx) control. Get to understand the control by building a basic (static) Chart firstly, then you can explore how to update it dynamically.